# using R's c code in my standalone executables: "Undefined symbols"

Tags: r, c, gcc

Suppose I have the following c source code, in `dexp_test.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

double dexp(double x, double scale, int log);

int main() {
  double x;
  x = dexp(1 , 2,  0);
  printf("Value: %f\n", x);
  return 0;
}
```

where `dexp` is defined in R's source code (https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/nmath/dexp.c). I would like to compile this to a standalone executable. I have R 4.0 installed on my system. I have the following `gcc` lines:

```
gcc r-source/src/nmath/dexp.c -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/include -c -o a.o

gcc dexp_test.c -c -o b.o
```

These lines run just fine on my system and I am left with new files `a.o` and `b.o` without errors.

When I run this line to get an executable:

```
gcc -o test_exp a.o b.o
```

...I get these errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_R_NaN", referenced from:
      _Rf_dexp in a.o
  "_R_NegInf", referenced from:
      _Rf_dexp in a.o
  "_dexp", referenced from:
      _main in b.o
     (maybe you meant: _Rf_dexp)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm definitely missing something conceptually here; how do I get this to compile? If it helps, I'm on OSX 15.6, and the output of `gcc -v` is

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should mention the operating system you are using.

You need to include the appropriate headers. And tell the linker where and which libraries you want to use.

So your source should be

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <R.h>
#include <Rmath.h>

int main() {
    double x;
    x = dexp(1 , 2,  0);
    printf("Value: %f\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

And on the command line you should use the following

```
gcc -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/include -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib -lR -o test_exp trydexp.c
```

Comment: OS was mentioned in the question. I'll edit to add the specific version of OSX. This does indeed solve the problem.

Comment: The answer isn't _exactly_  right as there is a dedicated library (normally called `libRmath`) that one should link with, rather tha actual shared library of the whole R system and interpreter. See [Writing R Extensions, Section 6.17](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Standalone-Mathlib).

Comment: In a standard R installation on macOS there is no standalone `libRmath` present.